# laravel undefined offset 1 - php artisan

Tags: php, laravel, exec, laravel-artisan

I'm running into the following error

> Undefined offset: 1

```
 Open: /home/vagrant/nomad/apps/immixcms/namespace/Cms/Site.php
```

Laravels debugging displays the following code block

```
     */
    public static function env($site)
    {
        $cname = 'site_env';

        if(!\Session::has($cname)) {
            $artisan = __DIR__ . "/../../../$site/artisan";
            $env = explode(': ', exec("php $artisan env"))[1];
            \Session::put($cname, $env);
        }
```

it seems the error is happening on the following line

```
        $env = explode(': ', exec("php $artisan env"))[1];
```